# how to reduce database size in firebase?

Tags: android, database, firebase, compression, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create an android app ( social network type app ) on the firebase Baas but due to its high pricing for database storage sizes i want to know the following :

if I try to reduce the size of the photo being uploaded to database before being saved , does this make the size of image smaller ? for example lets say the photo size is 500 x 500 and I save it in database as 250 x 250 does it become smaller in size and is this way an effecient way to use ? and does compressing photo on app before sending it make any difference in image size?

thanks in advance

Comment: The easiest way to reduce your cost would be to store the photos in [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) instead of the database.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen and how to know to which user it belongs ?

Comment: The same logic as you do in your database: store it in a folder for that user `/profilePics/<uid>/profile.jpg`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ok i understand you but i am sorry for my type of questions but i know that database is used to relate data enteties , if i do as u say how to know the relation between data , how to know this particular folder that has for example 1 photo how many like it has and from whom of his friends and sorry if i ask silly technical questions

Comment: Keep your profile photos in Firebase Storage. Keep your data (including the URL of the profile photo) in Firebase Database.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen you mean i put photos in firebase storage in folders/id/photos and put in the database schema photos entity instead of photo the URL of it in storage right ?

Comment: If that last "storage" was meant to say "database", then "yes". :-)

Comment: thanks man i want to mark your comment as accepted !!!

Comment: I'll write up an answer, although we probably answered something similar recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to reduce your cost would be to:

- store the photos in [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/)
- use a similar path in both case for user-specific data, i.e. `/users/<uid>/name` in the database vs `/users/<uid>/pic1.jpg` in storage
- store the URL of the photo in the [Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/), i.e. `/users/<uid>/profilePictureUrl: "https://storagedownloadURL/users/uid1/pic1.jpg?token=ajhksadkhjdasj"`

That way you get *both* near realtime synchronization of your structured data *and* cheap storage for your user-generated pictures.